# Access + VBA + SQL - How to export multiple queries into one excel Workbook, but, multiple Worksheet using the criteria from a table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access-2007

I need some help with export multiple queries into one excel Workbook, but, multiple Worksheet? using the criteria from a table in MS Access VBA

ATTACHED IS DB for Reference.

## Table name: Tbl_Final (columns listed below)

- System
- User ID
- User Type
- Status
- Job Position

Based on the Unique values in the column "System" in table "Tbl_Final" (SQL query below), I need to create INDIVIDUAL excel files and export it to folder.
Example:
SELECT TBL_FINAL.System, TBL_FINAL.[User ID], TBL_FINAL.[User Type], TBL_FINAL.Status, TBL_FINAL.[Job Position]
FROM TBL_FINAL
WHERE (((TBL_FINAL.System)="OS/400"));

```
    SELECT TBL_FINAL.System, TBL_FINAL.[User ID], TBL_FINAL.[User Type], TBL_FINAL.Status, TBL_FINAL.[Job Position]
    FROM TBL_FINAL
    WHERE (((TBL_FINAL.System)="Tab"));
```

After googling, i managed to find a code which matches the criterion. But encountring some hurdles :(

Request for some help !!

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    strQry = "REPORT_QUERY"

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strQry)

    strSQL = "SELECT System, [User ID], [User Type], [Status] FROM TBL_FINAL WHERE System = 'OS/400'"
    qdf.SQL = strSQL
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel11, _
        strQry, "C:\Program Files\Export\GENERAL_EXPORT.xls", True, _
        "Sheet1"
    
    strSQL = "SELECT System, [User ID], [User Type], [Status] FROM TBL_FINAL WHERE System = 'MySys'"
    qdf.SQL = strSQL
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel11, _
        strQry, "C:\Program Files\Export\GENERAL_EXPORT.xls", True, _
        "Sheet2"
    
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strQry

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

The following VBA code works for me, creating a new Excel workbook (`.xlsx` file) containing multiple worksheets (`mySheet1` and `mySheet2`):

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToXlsx()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set cdb = CurrentDb

    Const xlsxPath = "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.xlsx"

    ' create .xlsx file if it doesn't already exist, and add the first worksheet
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("mySheet1", _
            "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID Between 1 And 5")
    Set qdf = Nothing
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "mySheet1", xlsxPath, True
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "mySheet1"

    ' file exists now, so this will add a second worksheet to the file
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("mySheet2", _
            "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID Between 6 And 10")
    Set qdf = Nothing
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "mySheet2", xlsxPath, True
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "mySheet2"

    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that the name of the worksheet is taken from the name of the query (or table) being exported. If a worksheet with that name does not exist in the Excel file then it will be added.

Comment: Interstingly enough, this `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Table4", "test.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Query6", "test.xlsx", True` will create two new sheets in `test.xlsx`, even if the file already exists. The new sheets will be named according to the query or table name. I use this regularly for survey analysis.

Comment: @Remou Yes that's true, and that's what my code was doing. I added a few more comments to the answer to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gord, Using the above code, i was able to export the excel to the path hardcoded in the path. I was able to find the code which prompts the user to select the filepath where the export should be saved. I would like to know, how to include this in the code and append the Unique "System" value for each file. Example: 

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "mySheet2", xlsxPath & "OS400" &, True

Comment: Sub FolderPicker()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim path As String
    Dim notCancel As Boolean
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fd
        notCancel = .Show
        If notCancel Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
        MsgBox "The selected folder is " & path, vbInformation
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Comment: @user3217907 Change `Sub FolderPicker()` to `Function FolderPicker() As String` and have it return the `path` value. In your main code do `xlsxPath = FolderPicker()` and then try the revised `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` in your recent comment. If you get stuck then ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).