# Export two Access Queries to one excel file onto their own sheets

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two access Queries that I want to export to the same workbook but on different sheets.  Query1 and Query2 need to be put onto an excel file that ill name "QueryOverall", and on separate sheets. As of now it only lets me export one query to one excel file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access + VBA + SQL - How to export multiple queries into one excel Workbook, but, multiple Worksheet using the criteria from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251034/access-vba-sql-how-to-export-multiple-queries-into-one-excel-workbook-but)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet acExport, acSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Query1", "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Email\QueryOverall.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet acExport, acSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Query2", "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Email\QueryOverall.xlsx", True
```

Where `strFilePath` is the path to the file you're wanting. This will create two `Worksheets` within the same `Workbook`, one for each query.

**Edit:**

Example of use:

```
Sub go()
    Dim strFilePath as String
    strFilePath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Email\"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet acExport, acSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Query1", strFilePath + "QueryOverall.xlsx", True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet acExport, acSpreadSheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Query2", strFilePath + "QueryOverall.xlsx", True

End sub
```

You can also manually export them: Right-click on query > export > choose where > export to same file

Comment: Run this through the VBA "insert" Module correct? and also for the strFilePath, am I including the workbook at the end?

Comment: How are your queries being ran? Are they just being ran from a form, or being called in a sub? And yes, for the `strFilePath` you can set it to where ever the file is located (ex. `strFilePath = C:\users\me\desktop\`) and then just make sure you have the same file name, else it will create a new file (separate workbooks)

Comment: `Sub go()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadSheetTypeExcell12Xml, "Query1", "strFilePath = C:\Users\me\Desktop\Email" + "QueryOverall.xlsx", True
                                                                                    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadSheetTypeExcell12Xml, "Query2", "strFilePath = C:\Users\me\Desktop\Email" + "QueryOverall.xlsx", True

End Sub`